# Use a named range in a scatter chart

Tags: excel, charts

I would like to plot data that is not consecutively written in a column in an Excel 2010 scatter chart. In order to do it I named two ranges that look like `=A5,A10...A1000`as name1 and name2. I had to use names as the ranges were to big to be handled by the "select data" windows, despite the amount of data is perfectly plotted if they were consecutively written in a column. Then I tried to write the defined names when selecting the data, but an error was prompted. I could avoid the error by writing `={"name1"}`, which worked just for the X axis data. When I use the same syntax for y axis, it is transformed to `={0}`.

I have read about many dynamic charts using the offset function, but I think this is too much for what I wanted: simple fixed named ranges.

Is there any way to assign named ranges to a scatter chart without using the offset function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question, I've asked this myself but never bothered to get the answer Before! For some reason, charts do not seem to take workbook global variables for input. You have to use sheet local named ranges, as I show below:

[image]

Edit: it works with named ranges of non-consecutive cells too, as the question asks for
[image]

Comment: I changed the "Scope" of the named ranges, but Excel does not plot the chart. Could you click on the series in the chart and copy&paste the series definition it appears on the formula bar? please.
For a normal series it reads like `=SERIES("Title",sheet1!$C$4:$C$10,sheet1!$D$4:$D$10,1)`.
The furthest I can go is `=SERIES("Title",{"myxval"},sheet1!$D$4:$D$10,1)` (btw this does not plot the data), but when I change the y values to `{"myyval"}` I get `=SERIES("Title",{"myxval"},{0},1)`

Comment: sure, here is the series definition pasted from the formula bar: =SERIES(;local!myyval;local!myxval;1)

Comment: Excel 2010, (and using ";" as parameter delimiters due to national settings), diagram originally created by selecting both column of data and choosing the scatter-plot tool on the menu-bar, then editing directly the series definition

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know what I was doing wrong. I wrote the formula bar input as you wrote it and it worked. The only difference in my spreadsheet is that Excel changed the y axis from `Sheet1!valy` to `Book1!valy` as shown here  `=SERIES("Title",Sheet1!valx,Book1!valy,1)`.

Comment: Sorry, Excel didn't change anything, I defined `valy` as global by mistake.
I could defined the two variables as global, and it also worked.